# Can't make two containers stay next to each other [BOOTSTRAP GRID-LAYOUT]

Tags: grid-layout, bootstrap-grid

I'm trying to recreate this layout, but I don't know how to make the second container stay next to the first one. I tried adding height and width to the divs and containers, but it stays under the red block. I also tried setting the alignment to *in-block*, but it didn't work either. [image]

https://codepen.io/jimdiew/pen/XWXwEOa

```html
 <style>
      .sin-padding {padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}
      .col-3 { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
      .box-1 {height: 200px;}
      .col-6{flex:50%; max-width:50%;}
      .row {display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    
<!-- FIRST CONTAINER -->     
        <div class="col-6 sin-padding">
        
        <div class="box-1" style="background-color: red;">
        Big Project
        </div>
    </div>
    
<!-- SECOND CONTAINER -->
    <div class="col-6 sin-padding">

<!-- FIRST ROW-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6" style="background-color: blue;">
            Project 1
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-6" style="background-color: green;">
            Project 2
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- SECOND ROW-->        
        <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-6" style="background-color: purple;">
            Project 3
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-6" style="background-color: cyan;">
            Project 5
            </div>
        </div>            
       
    </div>
```

**EDIT 1 :** I changed the *col-3* of the second container to *col-6* as I think It was more appropiate.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<style>
  .sin-padding {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  .col-3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .box-1 {
    height: 200px;
  }
  .box-2 {
    height: 100px;
  }

  .col-6 {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <!-- FIRST CONTAINER -->
    <div class="col-6 sin-padding">
      <div class="box-1" style="background-color: red;">
        Big Project
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SECOND CONTAINER -->
    <div class="col-6 sin-padding">
      <!-- FIRST ROW-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 box-2" style="background-color: blue;">
          Project 1
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 box-2" style="background-color: green;">
          Project 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- SECOND ROW-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 box-2" style="background-color: purple;">
          Project 3
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 box-2" style="background-color: cyan;">
          Project 5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

what you missed was putting the first box and second set of boxes in a row class.

**Update:**
I noticed the code was missing closing body tag and starting head tag

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question. When I run the code I see that the horizontal scroll activates and a part of the first container is cutted out. 
Photo of what I'm saying (https://ibb.co/HNrHRk2)

Comment: @Jimdiew did you run the exact code above in the answer?

Comment: @Jimdiew please try the updated snippet. it is working properly and is responsive as well. make sure your CSS is not being overwritten by any other css

Comment: Oh, you are right! I already changed that but the problem is still there :/ the only css apart of the inline and internal one is the bootstrap.min.css , but i don't think that's the problem..